# Python: Create a function that takes an expression and prints both the expression as a string and its result

Tags: python

When running code from the console, I'd like both the command and its output to be printed, and I was wondering if there was a way to avoid typing the expression twice.

Instead of:

```
print("max(3,4): ", max(3,4))
```

I'd like a function:

```
f = def(x):
    print(.....)
```

where `f(max(3,4))` prints out the "Instead of" output:

```
f(max(3,4))
>>max(3,4): 4
```

Is this possible at all?

Comment: Depending on what you're doing this for, you might be interested in [MacroPy](https://github.com/azazel75/macropy). Or, if it's for debugging purposes, there's a library whose name escapes me that does it with frame hack. If you want to actually use this for "production code", however, that's probably a bad idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need `eval()`:

```
def f(expr:str):
    print("{}: {}".format(expr, eval(expr))

f("3 + 4 + max(2, 5)")
```

Output:

```
3 + 4 + max(2, 5): 12
```

Comment: I didn't know the eval function which might be handy for running a bunch of commands from a dataframe or something. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Just for fun, install the [`astor`](http://astor.readthedocs.io/) library, and:

```
import ast
import inspect
import astor

def printexpr(x):
    cc = inspect.stack(1)[1].code_context[0].strip()
    tree = ast.parse(cc)
    for node in ast.walk(tree):
        if isinstance(node, ast.Call):
            if node.func.id == 'printexpr':
                out = astor.to_source(node.args[0]).strip().strip('()')
                print(f'printexpr({out}): {x}')
                return
```

And now:

```
>>> printexpr(2)
printexpr(2): 2
>>> printexpr(2 + 3)
printexpr(2 + 3): 5
>>> printexpr(math.pi)
printexpr(math.pi): 3.141592653589793
>>> if True:
...     printexpr(2)
>>> printexpr(2), printexpr(4)
printexpr(2): 2
printexpr(2): 4
>>> spam = printexpr
>>> spam(2)
>>> printexpr(2+3)
printexpr(2 + 3): 5
>>> printexpr(max(3,4))
printexpr(max(3, 4): 4
```

As you can see from the last few, this isn't foolproof:

- I'm assuming that there will only be one call to `printexpr` in the calling context.
- I'm assuming that it will actually be called `printexpr`.
- Because I decided it would be more clever to compile and decompile the source instead of `tokenize`-ing and tediously searching the tokens, I print `2+3` as `2 + 3`.
- I should have actually handled the parens instead of stripping off any possibly-excess outer parens and then adding a pair.

But anyway, this should gives you an idea of how you can do almost anything in Python… but sometimes you don't want to. :)

Comment: This is really interesting. There seems to be a lot of complicated commands to sift through, but thanks for the detailed response!

Comment: @AndrewYeh I kind of erred on the side of playing with as many fun things as possible instead of making it as usable and/or robust as possible. I looked for a nice debugging library that does this properly, but only found one that promises to add Python 2.6 support in the roadmap, so… Normally, of course, you'd just use the debugger itself, rather than simulating part of its job, so it makes sense that nobody's put much work into this in a well-known library.

Comment: I've been working through python tutorials and writing the python file before running it all in the command line with "python lesson.py". It was annoying having to match up the console output to the command I'd been writing which is why I asked this question. Thanks!